# Spring boot application crashes with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION error

Tags: java, spring-boot, thread-dump

I have a spring boot java application which crashes from time to time. The only thing I have is a thread dump file generated after a crash. Could somebody help me to analyze this thread dump because I don't see there something useful?
I have to attach a link to the file because it's to big to add it here like a text. [thread dump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KseoqSyt8AzZwMcrQOS8kfZCv2DH35jZ/view?usp=sharing)

**Update**
The problem has gone once I've deleted and created a DB schema (we are using postgres). But I have absolutely no idea how such a thread dump related to postgres. So I think the initial question is still relevant.

Comment: i am not going to open your google drive link. Sorry Buddy.

Comment: @want2learn so how else should I attach this log if stackoverflow says that it's too big to have it here?